# Unable to connect to server through VPN L2TP

Tags: vpn, l2tp

I have set my Server app (OSX) to use VPN feature, with L2TP, using a VPN Host Name who is a FQDN pointed to my public static IP. By default it came with a shared secret, and a small range of IP's. In the DNS settings i have this server and the router of this private network, both IP's are internal.

Since there is a port for L2TP (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944), i have done a port forwarding in this router, to my server, through UDP in port 1701.

I am not able to test this properly, because i have test it with other mac who is inside of the same private network as this server, with the FQDN. There i add login credentials like i am using internally and set the connection to be L2TP and added the shared key manually. The error that i am getting is:

> The VPN-L2TP server doesnt respond. Try to connect again. If this
>   problem continue, check the definitions and contact the Administrator
>   of the system.

Now i dont know if i am unable to connect because i am in the same network, or if i have config something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE2:

I add the IKE port (500) for port forwarding and still nothing.

In /var/log/ppp.log i have:

```
l2tp_get_router_address  
l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.1.254 from dict 1  
L2TP connecting to server '<FQDN>' (<IP>) ...
IPSec connection started
IPSec connection failed
L2TP IPSec agressive mode retry with DH group 2
l2tp_get_router_address  
l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.1.254 from dict 1  
L2TP connecting to server '<FQDN>' (<IP>) ...
IPSec connection started
IPSec connection failed
```

Comment: IIRC L2TP needs IKE which runs on a different port. Make sure you are allowing everything that is required. Turn on firewall logging, that may provide clues as to what is being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael! I have added port 500 for IKE for port forwarding and nothing. Then i have activated the firewall to see if it reach the server, and there was no registe of anything trying to access. I dont understand i have VPN activated in the server, and port forwarding config to reach the server. Right now the only port forwarding that i have is for port 80, i have a web service. There is more ports that needed port forwarding? It could be from being in the same network? I have no clue on how to solve this =/